# Is there a resource which explains the history of how the Leidenfrost effect was explained?

Tags: experimental-physics

The context is that I am trying to teach some middle school students that in science, a question could be posed/ an observation made but being able to answer or explain it, might take a couple of centuries or more. I am attempting this using the Leidenfrost effect.

I understand that Leidenfrost himself was not able to explain what was going on. Can someone tell me how understanding of this effect evolved and how we came to understand it finally? (to the extent we understand it today)

Comment: Can you remind us, please, of what the L effect is?

Comment: When a liquid is poured on a hot solid surface (temperature roughly double of the boiling point), the drops skid around on the surface and take much longer to turn to vapour. Discovered by Leidenfrost 250 years ago. Now understood to be because of a layer of vapour that forms below the drop that slows down the heat transfer to the rest of the drop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect

Comment: @VishnuAgnihotri  You should add that to the answer, because comments may be deleted.

Comment: From a quick perusal of the literature, a well-explained vapor layer mechanism does not seem to have come into existence until the 1920s or so. Coming up with a detailed answer will likely require quite a bit of work, unless tracing out the history has already been done in some publication I have not come across yet.